# setExitTransition(new Explode) and createCircularReveal() for Kitkat?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-5.0-lollipop

How do we implement new setExitTransition and Circle reveal effects on Kitkat ?
i am having trouble implementing this two methods in my app.
I appreciate if someone could help me out.
i am sure many others also facing same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The `setExitTransition` method, the `Explode` transition, and the circular reveal animation were all added in Lollipop and there is currently no backwards-compatible way to run them on previous versions of the platform.

Comment: Oh i thought they have provided support library for that and i am the only one who is not able to find it.

Comment: There is currently no support library for Lollipop transitions.